# Ubuntu 20.04 - Wake on lan does not work on a bridged interface

Tags: networking, 20.04, network-bridge, wakeonlan

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 Server.  Using a basic DHCP setup, I was able to use WOL with no issues.  I had to build a service to ensure `ethtool -s enp1s0 g` stuck after a reboot.  WOL worked great.

Now I have installed a KVM virtual machine.  I set up a bridged interface called `br0` so that the virtual machine can pick up an IP address on my network.  That works great as well.

However now, WOL does not work. Any ideas as to what needs to be done to get WOL working when on a bridged network?

Thanks

Comment: I'm in exactly the same situation. WOL working fine until I added the bridge for the KVM. Did you ever manage to fix it?

Comment: Nope.  Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my pc after shutdown with active kvm machine, the kernel is "5.15.39-4-pve".

You have to stabilize bridge port's mac address so it won't change.

See: https://backreference.org/2010/07/28/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports/index.html

There are other questions you might got insights.

- [wake-on-lan doesn't work on bridged interfaces](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bridge-utils/+bug/538817)
- https://github.com/hansode/linux-bridge-mac-addresses-and-dynamic-ports

Hope it helps.